# Using the this pointer in a dependent derived class template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, this, name-lookup

In the example [pointers/countingptr.hpp](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/pointers/countingptr.hpp.html) of the book [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/tmplbook.html) members of the derived dependent `class CountingPtr` are referred to using the `this` pointer. Why is `this` necessary in this example?

I'm aware that the `this` pointer is required in order to name members of a dependent base class template. Surely the `this` pointer is not required in dependent derived class template also?

Comment: Have you tried leaving it out?

Comment: No. I'm studying the text and I assumed that its there for a reason I do not (yet) understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's just a style of the guy who was making this code. Some people prefer putting `this->` in front of anything that is related to a class inside that class. That indeed *may* sometimes be useful if you are doing funny things like:

```
void foo( int a )
{
this->a = a;
}
```

or if you just think this increases readability.
However, if you use it too much, it will be a mess:

```
this->a = this->b * this->c - this->foo( this->d, this->bar() );
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not needed. Some people use `this` everywhere.

Comment: Strange. Its the first time in the book the authors decided to be `this` explicit. Pun intended.

Comment: If you always use `this`, then you won't forget it for the dependent base members.

Answer (score 0):

> not required in **dependent derived class**

In what?

There is no "dependent derived class". The derived class is the derived class.

> derived class **template**

It is a class template, but **it is parsed as a class**.

Think of it this way:

It is not a class template, just a class (a type). A class template specialisation, but still a class, like a normal class.

Or this way:

The derived class template is instantiated with a "magical lazy type" argument. This lazy type argument suspends the compilation of any expression which depends on it.